# Probability with unknown sample mean and unknown standard deviation

Tags: probability, self-study, computational-statistics

I am studying statistics in a textbook. I have successfully answers two questions about normal distribution. Here are the questions

1. Credit scores are three-digit numbers used by lenders when evaluating your credit worthiness

   A.  Construct a histogram of the credit scores. Do the credit scores
   appear approximately normally distributed? Explain.

   B.Construct a normal probability plot (QQ-plot) of the credit
   scores. Do the credit scores appear approximately normally
   distributed? Explain.

   C. If your answer in (b) is yes, find the probability that a city will have a credit score of at
   least 680. Use the sample mean of the data for (miu) , and the sample standard deviation for (s).
   Here is the data for the questions :

   670
   705
   680
   690
   653
   675
   675
   655
   667
   672
   707
   688
   671
   688
   660
   676
   686
   691
   675
   693

For questions 1A , i plot a histogram in R and test the normality using Minitab and the statistics test shows that data is normally distributed . 1B also normally distributed.
I want to ask how to work on 1C.
My work goes this way

P(x>680) =..

SD = (X - Mean) / z

SD=(680-Mean)/1.96

Does my answer from 1a and 1b correct? Because im not sure graphically i found some data out of the straight line. And how can i do 1C for this? im stuck from SD and the Mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1C:

You can calculate the sample mean and standard deviation from the data given. Then, you want $P(X>680)$. Calculate $z=\frac{X-\mu}{s}=m$(say). Then $P(X>680)=P(z>m)=1-P(z<m)$. Check the [z-table](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~athienit/Tables/Ztable.pdf) for $z=m$. The value will give you $P(z<m)$.

---

Comment: Yes, i have calculate the mean and standard deviation from the mean, i get 0.07790146 as the result

Comment: I don't think the standard deviation is correct. Use $s^2=\frac{1}{N-1}\sum(x_i-\bar x)^2$